# Semi circle with rounded lines with CSS or SVG

Tags: html, css, svg, vector-graphics

I need semicircle merged with two lines with rounded corners, something like image.

[image]

My attempt:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <path style="fill: rgb(216, 216, 216); stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);" d="M36.8 31.6 142.9 30.9M142 30.2C155.2 74.5 211.3 87.9 243.1 54.3 249.5 47.5 254.3 39.2 257 30.2M256.3 30.9 362.3 30.3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" stroke="#808600"/>
</svg>
```

Need help with rounded corners of lines.

Comment: Use an SVG editor such as Inkscape and draw whatever you need.

Comment: For a single d-path use: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/#

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a shape that approximates what you describe.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
    viewBox="0 0 500 500"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path
        style="fill:#d8d8d8;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
        d="m 20,20 c 0,0 66.666667,0 100,0 16.24206,0 16.31485,10.20851 20,20 15.66983,41.63492 80.67624,42.9855 100,0 5.80507,-12.91332 5.07447,-20 20,-20 33.33333,0 100,0 100,0"
    />
</svg>
```

Here's an image showing what that SVG looks like:
[image: SVG image preview]

I was able to create that using Inkscape (free, open source). Take a look here if you are interested. https://inkscape.org/

If you want to create SVG files manually, you can use the path element and learn the commands to make any shape you want. Here's a good reference for the path element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

I hope that helps!